# @nrwl/nx + VS Code + ESLint - Errors highlighting doesn't work

Tags: eslint, nrwl-nx, eslintrc, typescript-eslint, nrwl

Linting shows errors in terminal but won't highlight the code in VS Code. ESLint extension is installed.

Running `nx lint`:

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ nx lint

> nx run public:lint [existing outputs match the cache, left as is]

Linting "public"...

/Users/honzachalupa/Projects Repositories/- BrightWorks/darek-na-svatbu/packages/public/src/components/organisms/content-blocks/About.tsx
  11:8  warning  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setNavigationRef'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

/Users/honzachalupa/Projects Repositories/- BrightWorks/darek-na-svatbu/packages/public/src/components/organisms/content-blocks/FAQ.tsx
  11:8  warning  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setNavigationRef'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

/Users/honzachalupa/Projects Repositories/- BrightWorks/darek-na-svatbu/packages/public/src/components/organisms/content-blocks/HowItWorks.tsx
  11:8  warning  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setNavigationRef'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

/Users/honzachalupa/Projects Repositories/- BrightWorks/darek-na-svatbu/packages/public/src/components/organisms/forms/EventCreate_Step1.tsx
  52:20  warning  Forbidden non-null assertion  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion

/Users/honzachalupa/Projects Repositories/- BrightWorks/darek-na-svatbu/packages/public/src/components/organisms/forms/EventCreate_Step2.tsx
  53:17  warning  Forbidden non-null assertion  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion

/Users/honzachalupa/Projects Repositories/- BrightWorks/darek-na-svatbu/packages/public/src/helpers/firebase.ts
  41:5  warning  Forbidden non-null assertion  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion

/Users/honzachalupa/Projects Repositories/- BrightWorks/darek-na-svatbu/packages/public/src/pages/Event/Checkout/Checkout.tsx
  106:43  warning  Forbidden non-null assertion  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
  110:50  warning  Forbidden non-null assertion  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion

/Users/honzachalupa/Projects Repositories/- BrightWorks/darek-na-svatbu/packages/public/src/pages/Event/Detail/Detail.tsx
  64:30  warning  Forbidden non-null assertion  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion

/Users/honzachalupa/Projects Repositories/- BrightWorks/darek-na-svatbu/packages/public/src/pages/Event/Detail/components/Catalog/Catalog.tsx
  134:35  warning  Forbidden non-null assertion  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
  265:49  warning  Forbidden non-null assertion  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion

/Users/honzachalupa/Projects Repositories/- BrightWorks/darek-na-svatbu/packages/public/src/pages/Event/Edit/Edit.tsx
  28:32  warning  Forbidden non-null assertion  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion

✖ 12 problems (0 errors, 12 warnings)


———————————————————————————————————————————————

>  NX   SUCCESS  Running target "lint" succeeded

  Nx read the output from cache instead of running the command for 1 out of 1 tasks.


>  NX   CLOUD  See run details at https://nx.app/runs/jfvJdo71MxA

✨  Done in 1.27s.
```

package.json dependencies:

```
    ...,
    "dependencies": {
        "@firebase/firestore": "^3.4.1",
        "@react-pdf/renderer": "^2.0.21",
        "core-js": "^3.20.0",
        "firebase": "^9.6.1",
        "firebase-admin": "^10.0.1",
        "firebase-functions": "^3.16.0",
        "logrocket": "^2.1.2",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "polished": "^4.1.3",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-day-picker": "^7.4.10",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.22.2",
        "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
        "react-is": "17.0.2",
        "react-qr-code": "^2.0.3",
        "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.22",
        "regenerator-runtime": "0.13.9",
        "styled-components": "5.3.3",
        "tslib": "^2.3.1",
        "usehooks-ts": "^2.1.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^13.1.2",
        "@babel/core": "7.16.5",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.16.5",
        "@nrwl/cli": "13.3.9",
        "@nrwl/cypress": "13.3.9",
        "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "13.3.9",
        "@nrwl/jest": "13.3.9",
        "@nrwl/linter": "13.3.9",
        "@nrwl/node": "^13.3.9",
        "@nrwl/nx-cloud": "latest",
        "@nrwl/react": "13.3.9",
        "@nrwl/storybook": "13.3.9",
        "@nrwl/tao": "13.3.9",
        "@nrwl/web": "13.3.9",
        "@nrwl/workspace": "13.3.9",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials": "~6.4.9",
        "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "^6.4.9",
        "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "~6.4.9",
        "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "~6.4.9",
        "@storybook/react": "~6.4.9",
        "@svgr/webpack": "^6.1.2",
        "@testing-library/react": "12.1.2",
        "@testing-library/react-hooks": "7.0.2",
        "@types/jest": "27.0.3",
        "@types/node": "17.0.0",
        "@types/react": "17.0.37",
        "@types/react-dom": "17.0.11",
        "@types/react-is": "17.0.3",
        "@types/styled-components": "5.1.18",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~5.7.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~5.7.0",
        "assert": "^2.0.0",
        "babel-jest": "27.4.5",
        "babel-loader": "8.2.3",
        "babel-plugin-styled-components": "2.0.2",
        "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
        "buffer": "^6.0.3",
        "cypress": "^9.1.1",
        "eslint": "8.5.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.3",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.27.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
        "jest": "27.4.5",
        "jest-styled-components": "^7.0.8",
        "prettier": "^2.5.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
        "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
        "ts-jest": "27.1.2",
        "typescript": "~4.5.4",
        "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
        "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.2"
    }
}
```

Workspace's .eslintrc.json:

```
    "root": true,
    "ignorePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "plugins": ["@nrwl/nx"],
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx", "*.js", "*.jsx"],
            "rules": {
                "@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries": [
                    "error",
                    {
                        "enforceBuildableLibDependency": true,
                        "allow": [],
                        "depConstraints": [
                            {
                                "sourceTag": "*",
                                "onlyDependOnLibsWithTags": ["*"]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "react/jsx-pascal-case": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
            "extends": ["plugin:@nrwl/nx/typescript"],
            "rules": {
                "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": 0,
                "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
                "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "files": ["*.js", "*.jsx"],
            "extends": ["plugin:@nrwl/nx/javascript"],
            "rules": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Project's .eslintrc.json:

```
    "extends": ["plugin:@nrwl/nx/react", "../../.eslintrc.json"],
    "ignorePatterns": ["!**/*"],
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx", "*.js", "*.jsx"],
            "parserOptions": {
                "project": ["apps/public/tsconfig.*?.json"]
            },
            "rules": {}
        },
        {
            "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
            "rules": {}
        },
        {
            "files": ["*.js", "*.jsx"],
            "rules": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the same problem, but I managed to at least format the code on save, even if it's not showing the errors.
I changed my settings.json on VSCode to add `editor.defaultFormatter`, and my typescript settings looks like this:

```json
"[typescript]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
          "source.fixAll": true,
        }
      },
```